# Why Django ORM make select query before deleting an object?

Tags: django, orm

I have two simple models:

```
class Image(Model):
    photo = models.CharField()

class Box(Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    image = models.ForeignKey(Image, blank=True, null=True)
```

When I want to delete Image's object, Django make select query on Box models:

```
>> Image.objects.all()[0].delete()

>> print len(connection.queries)

2

>> connection.queries

{u'time': u'0.000', u'sql': u'QUERY = u\'SELECT "box"."id", ... FROM "box" WHERE "image"."image_id" IN (%s)\' - PARAMS = (1,)'}
{u'time': u'0.000', u'sql': u'QUERY = u\'DELETE FROM "image" WHERE "id" IN (%s)\' - PARAMS = (1,)'}
```

Django 1.6b2

I've tried with `on_delete=models.SET_NULL`, also with sqlite and PostgreSQL always the same result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When Django deletes an object it tries to emulate the cascade deletion for related objects to ensure that their `delete` methods and related signals are called. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/queries/#deleting-objects

> When Django deletes an object, by default it emulates the behavior of the SQL constraint ON DELETE CASCADE – in other words, any objects which had foreign keys pointing at the object to be deleted will be deleted along with it.

With Django 1.5+ you can fast path the deletion by setting the foreign keys to `on_delete=DO_NOTHING`. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.delete

> Django needs to fetch objects into memory to send signals and handle cascades. However, if there are no cascades and no signals, then Django may take a fast-path and delete objects without fetching into memory. For large deletes this can result in significantly reduced memory usage. The amount of executed queries can be reduced, too.